# Auto-Implemented Properties without get gives Compilation Error

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

```
public int MyWriteOnlyProperty1 { set; }      /* Error: Auto-Implemented properties must have get accessors.*/
public int MyWriteOnlyProperty2 { set { } }   // No error
```

Why is there compile-time error for one, but no-error for other one? 
Is there any meaningful difference between the two, because of which it was decided that way?

Comment: probably the 2nd property isn't being auto-implemented anymore...you could compare the MSIL to go sure

Comment: What would be the use of it?

Comment: the meaningful difference is that one tries to auto-implement set (compiler would create a hidden variable which would be inaccessible), the other is explicitly doing nothing which is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one isn't auto implemented. In this simple case it would of course be possible for the compiler to go and figure out that your property implementation is broken (since setter doesn't do anything) but it would be hard to cover every possible case of "this property is broken" so I guess that's why they don't bother except for auto-implemented properties where it's trivial.

E.g. consider this, valid but weird usage of properties:

```
private int _myValue;
public int MyWriteOnlyProperty2 { set { _myValue = value; } }
```

Or this example where the property is just as broken as your example, but now it's hard for the compiler to know. Better just leave it up to the developer.

```
public int MyWriteOnlyProperty2 { set { DoNothing(value); } }
private void DoNothing(int value) { //Does nothing }
```

Comment: I think not doing anything is a valid way to implement a setter. For example, the property could represent a setting that's not relevant for this type, but has to be implemented to satisfy an interface.

Comment: A property with only a `set` is not that weird. A common place you will see it is for a `Password` property that can be assigned to but not read back out. [`DirectoryEntry.Password`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.password(v=vs.110).aspx) is a example of it in the framework.

Comment: Microsofts own design guidelines states that you should not use properties with only setters, so I thonk it is safe to call it weird. If you need to use that pattern define a method instead.

Answer (score 2):

The second one isn't auto-implemented. You're explicitly implementing the setter with an empty body. It's unusual to have a set-only property, but it's valid. And it's not the compiler's job to tell you what the implementation should look like, so an empty body is valid.

But the first case doesn't make any sense. Auto-implemented properties use an otherwise inaccessible backing field. With them, having both `get` and `set` (with same or different accessibility) makes perfect sense. Having just `get` (which is valid in C# 6.0) sounds a bit weird at first, but it does makes sense, since you can actually set the backing field in the constructor.

But having just `set`? That's not useful, there is no reason why you would want to write to a field that can't be read from. (And reading only in the constructor doesn't make sense either.)